# Show text whitin the bar - jQuery plot Vertically stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

I would like to show labels on each series of the stacked bar.Any idea please. I have been looking with no luck.
For example if you have blue series text will be blue on the series of the stacked bar and so on.

It should be something like that as you can see in the image :

[image]

Here is my code:-

```
    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
    var data = [
    {label: 'foo', color:'red', data: [[1,300], [2,300], [3,300], [4,300], [5,300]]},
    {label: 'bar', color:'blue', data: [[1,800], [2,600], [3,400], [4,200], [5,0]]},
    {label: 'baz', color:'yellow', data: [[1,100], [2,200], [3,300], [4,400], [5,500]]},
     ];

      $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
      series: {
      stack: 1,
      bars: {
        show: true,
        lineWidth: 1,
        barWidth: 0.8,
        order: 1, 
        fill: true, 
            label: {
            show: true,
            radius:0.7,

            formatter: function(label, series) {
                 var result =[ <?php echo $red; ?> ,<?php echo $blue; ?> ,<?php                 
            echo $yellow; ?>

            ];

              if ( label == "red")
               { 
                 return '<div style="font-size:13px; text-align:center; left:-340px; top:-338px;                       
               position:absolute; color:white;">'+label+'<br/>'+(result[0])+'</div>';
               }
               else if (label == "blue")
               { 
                 return '<div style="font-size:13px; text-align:center; left:-343px; top:-228px;                         
                    position:absolute; color:white;">'+label+'<br/>'+(result[1])+'</div>';
               }
               else if (label == "yellow")
               { 
                 return '<div style="font-size:13px; text-align:center; left:-325px; top:-220px;  
               position:absolute; color:white;">'+label+'<br/>'+(result[2])+'</div>';
               }



           },
            background: {
                opacity: 0.8,

            }
        }     
    },
    yaxis : {
        min : 0,
        tickLength: 0
    } ,
    xaxis: {
    tickLength: 0,
    axisLabel: "Date",
    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Arial',
    axisLabelPadding: 3,
    color: "#838383",
    timeformat: "%b/%y"
    }
    }
    });
```

Comment: You just asked the same question.  It was closed as a duplicate.  Did you look at those questions and attempt to implement the solution they provided?  We aren't here to do your work for you.

Comment: @Mark I didn't ask for your help ! Okay ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the valuelabels plugin to get this to work.

Reference: https://github.com/winne27/flot-valuelabels/wiki

Download: https://github.com/winne27/flot-valuelabels/blob/master/jquery.flot.valuelabels.js

Basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/WetNoodles/6b8n4nhe/1/

With the plugin, you can specify these options on each data series:

`valueLabels: {
    show: true,
    valign: 'middle'
}`

Comment: It prints the value is it possible to print a text instead of value ? Many thanks for your kind help.

Comment: You're welcome! You should be able to use the `labelFormatter` option in the `valueLabels` object. Unfortunately, it does not look like it has any default way to convert to dates like flot does, but hopefully your values won't be too tough to convert to months.

Comment: You see the sky color how I can change it to green ? Thank you so much

Comment: and I would like to have a bigger size for valueLabels ?How do I change it ? Thank you

Comment: You can use the `'font-color'` and `font` options which take any valid css value. You can see all these options at this link  https://github.com/winne27/flot-valuelabels/wiki

Comment: Thank you.How to increase the size of the ValueLabels with the example you had in JSFiddle ? Thanks a lot

Comment: It looks like you have to specify both a font size and a family. Here's is an updated link with the example: http://jsfiddle.net/WetNoodles/6b8n4nhe/2/